# Вложенные итераторы

Tags: java

Добрый день решаю задачу про вложенные итераторы.

Задача: 
реализовать класс с методом `Iterator<Integer> onvert(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it)`.

Что из себя представляет запись `Iterator<Iterator<Integer>`?.

Каждый итератор это последовательность.

Итератор 1 – 4 2 0 4 6 4 9

Итератор 2 – 0 9 8 7 5

Итератор 3 – 1 3 5 6 7 0 9 8 4

Если мы говорим о записи Итератор Итераторов. Значит итератор содержит не конечные значения, а сложенные итераторы.

Итератор - Итератор 1, Итератор 2, Итератор 3.

Метод convert должен принимать объект итератор итератор и возвращать Итератор чисел.

`Iterator<Iterator<Integer>` - ((4 2 0 4 6 4 9), (0 9 8 7 5), (1 3 5 6 7 0 9 8 4))

Метод должен возвращать

`Iterator<Integer>` - (4 2 0 4 6 4 9 0 9 8 7 5 1 3 5 6 7 0 9 8 4)

Метод не должен копировать данные. Нужно реализовать итератор, который будет пробегать по вложенными итераторам без копирования данных.

Шаблон класса

```
public class Converter {
   Iterator<Integer> convert(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it) {
      return new Iterator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
           return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
           return null;
        }
     };
   }
}
```

Тест

```
    Iterator<Integer> it;

    @Before
    public void setUp () {
        Iterator<Integer> it1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).iterator();
        Iterator<Integer> it2 = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6).iterator();
        Iterator<Integer> it3 = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9).iterator();
        Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> its = Arrays.asList(it1, it2, it3).iterator();
        IteratorIterator IteratorOfIterators = new IteratorIterator();
        it = IteratorOfIterators.convert(its);
    }


    @Test
    public void hasNextNextSequentialInvocation () {
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next(), is(1));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next(), is(2));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next(), is(3));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next(), is(4));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next(), is(5));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next(), is(6));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next(), is(7));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next(), is(8));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next(), is(9));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(false));
    }
```

Мой код:

```
public class IteratorIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {


    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        return null;
    }

    Iterator<Integer> convert(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it) {
        Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> main = it;
        Iterator<Integer> iter = main.next();

        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
            boolean temp = false;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (main.hasNext()) {
                    if (iter.hasNext()) {
                        temp = true;
                    }

                    else {

                      main.next();

                        hasNext();
                    }

                }
                return temp;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                int temp = 0;
                if (main.hasNext()) {
                    if (iter.hasNext()) {
                        temp = iter.next();
                    } else {
                        main.next();

                    }

                }

                return temp;
            }


        };
    }
}
```

почему итератор проходит только по первому массиву чисел а на второй не переходит ? не пойму что тут не так .

Answer (score 1):

`main.next();` возвращает следующий элемент, почему вы его игнорируете?

`boolean temp = false;` - это у вас поле объекта `Iterator` установив его в `true` в `hasNext()`, вы потом всегда возвращаете `true`

В итераторе метод `next()` не должен вызывать метод `hasNext()` сам, это делает тот кто использует итератор.

При этом если `main.hasNext()` вернет вам `false`, то вы вернете ноль. Правильно ли это? Как это обработать со стороны вызова?

Comment: почему игнорирую он у меня должен срабатывать если внутренний метод возвращает false или я неправильно понимаю ?

Comment: метод то срабатывает, а вот результат его работы вы игнорируете. Метод next не присваивает владельце объект, он возвращает объект и как раз возвращаемый объект вы игнорируете

Comment: если  я правильно вас понял ,то iter = main.next но идея пишет что не может так переопределить

Comment: next это не переменная а метод.